# User Control Button Not Firing on Sharepoint Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-controls, buttonclick

I have a button that I am adding to a usercontrol(.ascx) that is being displayed in sharepoint as a webpart.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCCA_UserAdministration_NewUser" runat="server" Text="Request User" OnClick="btnCCA_UserAdministration_NewUser_Click" >
```

However the button click action will not fire:

```
protected void btnCCA_UserAdministration_NewUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnCCA_UserAdministration_NewUser.Visible = false;

        }
```

I am not getting any error messages or anything. The onload events seem to be working fine. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

we need more .ascx code, and try to change "to any CPU" in solutions